# Yii Cache, CDbCommand::execute() fail: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: YiiCache.id

Tags: yii, yii-components

I'm getting the following error with Yii cache

```
CDbCommand::execute() fail: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: YiiCache.id. La sentencia SQL
ejecutada fue: INSERT INTO YiiCache (id,expire,value) VALUES
('f5f5bcc0fd61886a71fba221738e512a',1550528514,:value).
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Extend component you are using for cache and catch this exception. This is usually due to requests making at the same time.

Comment: Thank you @SiZE let me try, then I'll post the result.

Comment: You shouldn't use DB as a cache in the first place - depending on case file cache or redis/memcache cache may give much better results.

Comment: @rob006 I'll check that one, I'm using SQLite to the cache, that is a Yii's utility.